# Fetching packages from old-releases.ubuntu.com fails with 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.10

I want to upgrade from 16.10 to a current release; following the [EOL Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/) wiki instructions I changed my repo URLs to old-releases.ubuntu.com, and `apt update` now completes successfuly, but upgrade fails with 404 Not Found errors for packages. Does this mean that it's impossible to upgrade 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) without doing a fresh install?

*Edit*: The instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) don't work since they result in errors like this:

`E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/bsdutils_2.28.2-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found`

Comment: 17.04 is already EOL, so the upgrade path is gone.  ie. It too is in `old-releases.ubuntu.com` where the upgrade-path doesn't look.  release-upgrade is now too late for 16.10, backup & install (a supported version of Ubuntu; and consider sticking to LTS or long-term support releases)

Comment: You should just do a fresh install, otherwise you'd be attempting 16.10 > 17.04 > 17.10. Less than 50-50 that works out well plus time consuming. As far as the old-release repos - while the packages list  index lists yakkety packages  in reality few are actually in the package pool. (if any). For example your bsdutils - goes from 2,26.2 (wily) to 2.29-1 (zesty). Maybe someone forgot to actually add yakkety packaes to the pool,  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/  maybe they're saving 'resources' (money), don't know.... so don't waste your time